# Is there a list of pragmas supported in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, gcc, pragma

Is there a list of pragmas supported in Xcode? I only know of `#pragma mark`. Where would I look to learn about any others?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GCC online manual, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html#Pragmas). Depending on your XCode settings, you can use GCC 4.0, 4.2, 4.4 (if present on your system) or even LLVM/GCC 4.2. Please refer to proper compiler version docs for specific information.

Comment: At least in the past, I have heard people for whom it mattered lament that Apple's compiler reported its version as "gcc 2.7.2.2" but was really patched in not-so-subtle ways by Apple (to the point of being observationally different from a real gcc 2.7.2.2). I do not know about the current situation, and do not think this would impact the syntax for pragmas.

Comment: On latest XCode (3.2 on Snow Leopard) GCC's version is reported the right way. In any case, you could do always type "gcc --version" in your console et voilà.

Comment: Just another bit of info. http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ provides latest **standard** version of GCC (now 4.4.1) for OSX versions. I use it with success for my projects, and it's compatible with XCode too (by defining it as default system compiler)

Comment: It gets worse. gcc --version with default xcode tells us its actually llvm. Which isnt actually gcc at all. Oh so many agitated debug sessions I've spent falling over this irritating piece of nonsense.